# activemq-all forces me to use log4j slf4j implementation

Tags: maven, log4j, activemq-classic, slf4j, logback

I would like to use the logback slf4j implementation in my application, but activemq-all is spoiling the classpath by including the log4j implementation classes. I'm not the only one facing that problem, as witnessed by for instance [multiple SLF4J bindings Error with activemq-all-5.6.0.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786265/multiple-slf4j-bindings-error-with-activemq-all-5-6-0-jar). According to that post I have to replace activemq-all by

```
org.apache.activemq:activemq-camel
org.apache.activemq:activemq-core
org.apache.activemq:activemq-console
org.apache.activemq:activemq-jaas
org.apache.activemq:activemq-optional
org.apache.activemq:kahadb
org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec
org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec
org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec
org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec.
```

The problem is that I don't have the complete maven dependencies (group id, artifact id, version) for these artifacts. Can someone provide me with a ready-to-use replacement for

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, you have already listed group id/artifact id **separated by a colon** for the artifact you found. Please note that these satisfy some usecase with ActiveMQ 5.6. For instance activemq-core is not really valid any more - use activemq-client and activemq-broker instead.

Currently, these artifact are bundled in activemq-all. But you may want to check out the [pom.xml](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=activemq.git;a=blob;f=activemq-all/pom.xml;h=3265af67c040f148d23c7c1990979a16649b4c47;hb=HEAD) for your version of choice (this list might change over time). You probably won't need all of them unless you are about to embedd a broker with all transports, plugins and configurations within your applications.

```
<artifactSet>
  <includes>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-client</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-openwire-legacy</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-camel</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-jaas</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-broker</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-console</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-shiro</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-spring</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-pool</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-jms-pool</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-amqp</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-http</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-mqtt</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-stomp</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-kahadb-store</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-leveldb-store</include>
    <include>${project.groupId}:activemq-jdbc-store</include>
    <include>org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf</include>
    <include>org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf</include>
    <include>org.jasypt:jasypt</include>
    <include>org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</include>
    <include>org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec</include>
    <include>org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec</include>
    <include>org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec</include>
    <include>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</include>
    <include>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12</include>
    <include>log4j:log4j</include>
  </includes>
</artifactSet>
```

Ok, the version number for org.apache.activemq should simply be the release you want to use. For the geronimo specs, this is not so obvious.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
   <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use active mq core library. Please note that active mq is backward compatible for client.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.3</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>                 
              <artifactId>org.slf4j</artifactId>
              <groupId>slf4j-log4j12</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>                 
              <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
              <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: did you mean artifactid and groupid in reverse? `
<exclusion>                 
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
</exclusion>`  as in [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.11)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this same issue with activemq-all API and I replaced this dependency with this below dependency and it worked for me.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
    <version>5.14.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this can help others.