# Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation

Tags: eclipse, osgi, rcp

I introduced a 3rd party plugin into my existing Eclipse RCP application and now my logging no longer works. It seems that it's using it's own version of slf4j.  How can I resolve this and have my slf4j and the one in the 3rd party jar co-exist in harmony?

```
  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
    org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. 
    Unable to resolve resource My3rdPartyLib.my3rdPartyLib_api [osgi.identity; 
    osgi.identity="My3rdPartyLib.my3rdPartyLib_api"; type="osgi.bundle"; 
    version:Version="2.4"] because it is exposed to package 'org.slf4j' 
    from resources slf4j.api [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="slf4j.api"; 
    type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.21"] and activemq-all 
    [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="activemq-all"; type="osgi.bundle"; 
    version:Version="5.9.0"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  My3rdPartyLib.my3rdPartyLib_api [osgi.identity; 
   osgi.identity="My3rdPartyLib.my3rdPartyLib_api"; type="osgi.bundle"; 
   version:Version="2.4"]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.slf4j
  slf4j.api [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="slf4j.api"; 
   type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.21"]

Chain 2:
  My3rdPartyLib.my3rdPartyLib_api [osgi.identity; 
   osgi.identity="My3rdPartyLib.my3rdPartyLib_api"; type="osgi.bundle"; 
   version:Version="2.4"]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.activemq)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.apache.activemq; uses:=org.slf4j
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j
  activemq-all [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="activemq-all"; 
   type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="5.9.0"]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

I tried including it as an RCP plugin. In the target->content view I checkmark the 3rd party jar and its necessary dependencies. I checkmark the slf4j jars that I need as well. If I run the product->validation it says 'no problems detected'. When I run it, it blows up with the message shown above.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is My3rdPartyLib.my3rdPartyLib_api exporting slf4j.api? Perhaps you can change it to just import it. You don't show whether activemq-all also exports slf4j.api. One idea maybe not to use activemq-all but instead use the individual activemq parts you need. -all bundles can be convenient but their package together in an uber bundle can fix certain constraints which upset other parts of the system.

Comment: Both manifests have multiple entries about slf4j being exported in the 'uses' sections.  I'm not sure what would happen if I removed them.  I figure there should be a way for the plugins to co-exist without me editing their manifests (especially since I didn't write them).  Does RCP/OSGI not support this?

Comment: Being listed in the uses directive does not mean it is exports. It does mean that a type from the used package is visible in the API of the exported package. Removing from the uses can lead to ClassCastExceptions at runtime when different class object for the same type name meet. I would say some of the fault here lies with activemq since it seems to "leak" slf4j types through its API.

Comment: So there is no way to isolate the 2 separate plugins from each other?

Comment: I don't see how you can when My3rdPartyLib.my3rdPartyLib_api wants to import org.apache.activemq from the other bundle. The only "solution" would be to modify one or both of the bundles so that they are both willing to use the same slf4j.api package. You don't show the manifests of both bundles to allow me to suggest a manifest change.

Comment: Unfortunately the manifests are so large that stackoverflow won't allow me to paste them onto this question :(

Comment: If I remove active-mq from the project, My3rdPartyLib complains about "Missing Constraint: Import-package, version=0.0.0" for the following 4 resources (javax.jms, org.apache.activemq, org.apache.activemq.command, org.apache.activemq.transport)

Comment: Ok, I downloaded those resources for activemq v5.9.0 but when I run the RCP application it complains that it can't find classes that only appear in the activemq-all jar (like ActiveMQConnectionFactory). Therefore I assume I must use the activemq-all jar instead of individual jars.  The way the import/export gets created in the manifest of activemq-all is by me creating an osgi wrapper using "java -jar bnd-2.4.0.jar activemq-all-5.9.0.jar".  Is there some parameters I should pass into that call which may help it play nicely with my other plugins?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out by taking your advice to breaking apart the 'all' jar and getting the pieces here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786265/multiple-slf4j-bindings-error-with-activemq-all-5-6-0-jar (and also 5.7.0 activemq-core). Thanks!